# field missing in the json response spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, postman, rest, get-mapping

I have Stock response class with only two fields as follows

```
class StockResponse {

private String orderId;
private String status;

//constructor

//getters and setters

}
```

and the also the controller as follows

```
@RestController
 @RequestMapping("/stocks")
 public class StockController {

 private static List<StockResponse> stocktList = new ArrayList <StockResponse > ();
 
 static {
     stocktList.add(new StockResponse("order1", "AVAILABLE"));
     stocktList.add(new StockResponse("order2", "AVAILABLE"));
     stocktList.add(new StockResponse("order3", "NOT AVAILABLE"));
     stocktList.add(new StockResponse("order4", "AVAILABLE"));
    
 }

 @GetMapping("/")
 public ResponseEntity < ? > getProsucts() {

  return ResponseEntity.ok(stocktList);

 }

 @GetMapping(path="/{id}", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
 public StockResponse getProsucts(@PathVariable String id) {

     StockResponse product = findOrder(id);
     
  if (product == null) {
 //  return ResponseEntity.badRequest(product)
 //   .body("Invalid product Id");
  }
  System.out.println(product.getOrderId());
  System.out.println(product.getStatus());
  

  return new StockResponse(product.getOrderId(), product.getStatus());

 }

 private StockResponse findOrder(String id) {
  return stocktList.stream()
   .filter(user -> user.getOrderId()
    .equals(id))
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(null);
 }


}
```

when I make a call to the localhost:8082/stocks/order1 I get a response with only one field showing up as follows
[image]

what could I be missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ensured that all my getters and setters are public,
I looked closely and I had missed public on

```
 public String getStatus()
```

Comment: Can you update the OP instead?

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce this, meaning it works for me.

Listing all stocks

```
$ curl -sS 'http://localhost:8080/stocks/' | jq "."
[
  {
    "orderId": "order1",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
  },
  {
    "orderId": "order2",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
  },
  {
    "orderId": "order3",
    "status": "NOT AVAILABLE"
  },
  {
    "orderId": "order4",
    "status": "AVAILABLE"
  }
]
```

Getting specific stock

```
$ curl -sS 'http://localhost:8080/stocks/order1' | jq "."
{
  "orderId": "order1",
  "status": "AVAILABLE"
}
```

My `StockController` is identical to yours. I also copy and pasted your `StockResponse` to get the field names identical to yours, but since you didn't include the constructor/getter and setter I'll show the one which works for me.

The way you're instantiating the `StockResponse` objects in the `stocktList` list is using the constructor and that might point to that you're not actually setting the `this.status` on the objects. If that doesn't work, double check that the getter for the status field is actually called `getStatus()`.

```
public class StockResponse {

    private String orderId;
    private String status;

    public StockResponse(String orderId, String status) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

The fact that your response contains a field that uses "non-standard" upper case for the first letter tells me that maybe you're doing something else that's not standard the might influence your result.

Comment: Thanks I looked closely and I had missed public on `public String getStatus() `